# CFG for language of all palindromes whose number of 1s is divisible by 3

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

The question is the following:

> Construct a CFG for $L_2 = \{w \in \{0, 1\}^* \mid w = w^R\text{ and the number of 1’s in $w$ is divisible by 3}\}$.

I can construct a CFG for $\{w \in \{0,1\}^* \mid w = w^R\}$ as follows

$$S → 1S1\mid 0S0\mid 0\mid 1\mid \epsilon$$

I don't understand how to make $w$ divisible by 3 in my CFG.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the ACTUAL answer 
$S_0 \rightarrow 0S_00 \ |\ 1S_11\ |\ 0\ |\ \epsilon$ 
$S_1 \rightarrow 0S_10\ |\ 1S_21\ |\ 1$ 
$S_2 \rightarrow 0S_20\ |\ 1S_01\ $

Comment: The last 11 is redundant.

Comment: True, thank you for pointing that out. I am very tired...

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the closure of context-free languages to intersection with a regular language.

In this case, though, it is simple enough to construct the grammar explicitly. The idea is to have three different symbols, $S_0,S_1,S_2$, where $S_b$ generates all palindromes in which the number of 1s is equivalent to $b$ mod 3. The productions for $S_0$ are
$$
S_0 \to 0S_00 \mid 1S_11 \mid 0 \mid \epsilon.
$$
I'll let you figure out the productions for $S_1,S_2$, as well as which symbol is the starting symbol.

Comment: Starting symbol will be S0. However I am unable to figure out exact productions of S1,S2. Can you provide a few hints perhaps?

Comment: No, you’ll have to work it out on your own.

Comment: Is this correct?
$$
S_1 \to 1\mid  1S_21 \mid S_01S_0 
$$

$$
S_2 \to S_1S_0S_1
$$

@Yuval Filmus

Comment: @hsnsd No, note the two $S_0$s in $S_01S_0$ may produce different strings. The productions for $S_1$ and $S_2$ are very similar to that for $S_0$. The idea is to consider separately the cases based on the first and the last characters.